# What's the difference between elseif and else if in Lua?

Tags: lua

What's the difference between `elseif` and `else if` in Lua? I don't know if they're the same but shorter.

```lua
x= 100
y= 100

if x > 90 then
  ...
else if y > 110 then
  ...
else
  ...
end
end

if x > 90 then
  ...
elseif y > 110 then
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: The difference is what you already know: if you use `else if`, then you need one `end` for each `if`. If you use `else if`, then you only need one `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `else if` in Lua.

The proper syntax is `elseif`.

Let's fix your intedation:

```
if x > 90 then
  ...
else
  if y > 110 then
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

It's just a bit more complicated. This only makes sense if you need more else blocks as well.
If there is only one else block for all conditions then elseif is sufficient.

Comment: There is `else if` in Lua but you then need one `end` for each `if`.